# core data for key-value in json field

Tags: ios, regex, core-data

In my application i need to query core data, i have a table which contains a field that stores a json string. Now i need to query this table for the any entry that has a specific key-value pair inside this field. I already tried to solve this with a LIKE expression but since the WILDCARDS DO MATCH THE NEWLINE this wasn't going so well. Now im stuck at figuring out which regex i have to use with the MATCHES operation.

**the key and a substring of the value are known and i just need to find the entry containing them,nothing else** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it with regex:

```
    for(NSString* value in values)
{
    if(value.length > 0)
    {
        if(i > 0)
        {
            [query appendString:@" OR "];

        }
        [query appendFormat:@" (json_data MATCHES[c] '.*?\"%@\\\":\\\"([^\"]*)%@([^\"]*)\".*?')",key,value];
        i++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a getter property to that entity, which returns just a normal string and not json string like:

```
- (NSString *)stringRepresentation
{ 
  NSError *error = nil; 
  NSData* data=[self.jsonStringProperty dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *string = [JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
  if (error) {
   ... // error handling
  }
  return string;
}
```

Then you can use a query with LIKE expression on that property